# Replace strings in file using list of substitutions and their locations

Tags: string, file, replace, text-processing

I have a file tree and a file containing a list of substitutions in that file tree that looks like this:

```
# filename:line:col original replacement
file.txt:10:5 foo Foo
file.txt:10:13 bar Bar
path/to/other.txt:1:3 baz BazBuzz
```

Note that there could be multiple substitutions per line, multiple substitutions per file, and the identifiers need not be the same length.

I am halfway through writing a program to manually read this file and apply the substitutions, but I wonder if there is a better way to bulk substitute specific instances of words in a file. I have seen solutions that do global replacements, but that is *not* what I want.

Comment: What are the two colon-separated numbers after the filename? Starting line number and # of lines?

Comment: @TomHebb I edited to clarify that they are lineno and colno.

Comment: So the replacement will only happen if "original" shows up at *exactly* the line and column number specified? What if there's something else at that position? Should it cause an error, or just silently ignore that entry?

Comment: It should be a hard failure; that means the data is bad and I need to go re-write my other program.